# jquery ajax gives always error status with form submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a simple html form and jquery. and all I want to run ajax function of jquery, but it always gives error response.

my code is

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.8.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post" id="messageForm">
<table border=1>
<tr><td>Name</td><td align=right><input type="text" name="from" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Surname</td><td align=right><input type="text" name="to" /></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2>Message</td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2><textarea name="message" rows=10 cols=50> </textarea></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan=2 align=right><input type="submit" value="Send"  /></td></tr>
</table>

</form>

<span id="textres">

</span>
<script lang="javascript">

 $("#messageForm").submit(function(event) {

 $.ajax({
  url: "ajax.php",
  data: $("#messageForm").serialize(),
  cache: false,
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
     //console.log or alert error
     alert("textStatus:"+textStatus+",errorThrown:"+errorThrown+",XMLHttpRequest:"+XMLHttpRequest);
  },
  success: function(html){
     alert("Data Loaded: "+html);
  }

});

});


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and, it never runs success event. when I look google chorome console, there is no error and if I copy the code of

```
 $.ajax({
  url: "ajax.php",
  data: $("#messageForm").serialize(),
  cache: false,
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
     //console.log or alert error
     alert("textStatus:"+textStatus+",errorThrown:"+errorThrown+",XMLHttpRequest:"+XMLHttpRequest);
  },
  success: function(html){
     alert("Data Loaded: "+html);
  }

});
```

to console, it works well. what should I do to run a simple jquery ajax function ?

Comment: What does your server code look like?

Comment: Also, you should wrap your jquery code in `$(document).ready(function(){`, to ensure it attaches the event correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `submit()` means the page will be refreshed, try this :

```
$("#messageForm").submit(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   ...
   return false;
})
```

Comment: excellent response. yes, submit event blocks something. anyway, thanks

Comment: I tried the code and this works for me. If it still doesn't work, check that ajax.php is in your server root and that the permissions allow it to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Beside this code:

```
 $("#messageForm").submit(function(event)
```

Try this code:

```
$("#sendButton").click(function(e){
    e.PreventDefault();
    //here goes the ajax code
}
```